# Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools on separate sub-domains

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, tracking, multi-subdomains

I am working on a site which has multiple subdomains to handle localisation. The site is translated into roughly 20 languages all with it's own subdomain, `example.com`, `en.example.com`, `es.example.com`, etc.

It all uses one set of templates and different data served primarily through `.json` files and hdf5 database.

I would like to install GA and WT on the site tracking each subdomain but under one profile. Is this possible or do I have to install separate profiles for each subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

I have a site that is set up the same way.   Tracking all the sites together is possible.

#### Google Webmaster Tools

If you add the bare domain `example.com` to GWT, it will be a rollup of all the subdomains.   You can also add individual subdomains separately and be able to see more individual information.

If you have your English site on the bare domain (as I do), there will *not* be a way of viewing the information for it separately.  In GWT the bare domain is *always* a rollup.

#### Google Analytics

Google Analytics can work well with multiple subdomains.  It will be able to track them all in the same account, as long as you do a little configuration.   It needs to be able to share the Analytics cookie between the subdomains, so you need to tell it to set the cookie on the bare domain.   [From the Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#multitrackers) you need code like this on all your pages:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain': 'example.com'});
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's a great help. I'll look into that and see what the requirements are.